# Data attribute with string array in JQuery Mobile

Tags: json, jquery-mobile

http://jsfiddle.net/673h38g9/17/

I am trying to fetch an array of data-attribute through Jquery mobile , but it says undefined.

```
<div data-stuff="['a','b','c']"></div>

var vendoritems = $('div').data('stuff');
alert(vendoritems);
var myid = 'd';
if (vendoritems.indexOf(myid) > -1) {
    $('div').data('stuff', vendoritems.push(myid))
    var vendoritemsss = $('div').data('stuff');

}
```

Is the data attr array not supported in JQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to

- run your JQuery code when `onDomReady`
- put your string data in double quotes (see [JSON spec](http://json.org/))
- access your div by id
- respect array.push return type (length, not array)

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/673h38g9/18/

```
var vendoritems = $('#data').data('stuff');
alert(vendoritems);
var myid = 'd';
if (vendoritems.indexOf(myid) < 0) {
    vendoritems.push(myid);
    $('#data').data('stuff', vendoritems);
    var vendoritems2 = $('#data').data('stuff');
    alert(vendoritems2);
}
```

Html:

```
<div id="data" data-stuff='["a","b","c"]'></div>
```